# PDF Generation in Magento is Really slow

Tags: performance, pdf, varnish, magento1.7.0.2

I have a problem with my Magento installation, at the hour of print the PDF with the invoices and packing Slips it is really slow, around 3-4 minutes in give the file in PDF.

No matter if u print 1 page or more, the time of the print is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the default fontfor PDF generation? This only effects the file-size, but it is such a significant reduction in size it may improve things for you.

copy the core file into local (local override)

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
```

Find the line which contains:

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . ‘/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertineC_Re-2.8.0.ttf’);
```

replace with:

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
```

In my case the original file size was near 1mb, afterwards it was 200K.